# Returning a static array without using a class field

Tags: c#

I have the following base and derived (partial, for sake of brevity) classes:

```
class Base {
     public abstract int[] someArray { get; }
}

class Derived : Base {
     private readonly static int[] _someArray = new int[] { 1,2,3,4 };
     public override int[] someArray { 
         get {
              return _someArray;
         }
     }
}
```

What I would like now, is put the `new int[] { 1,2,3,4 }` in the `return` part of the getter. But, that would create a new array every time the getter is called.

Is it possible to directly return some kind of object, which stays the same for all objects of class `Derived` ?

Something along the lines of (I know this is invalid C#):

```
  get {
        return (int[]) { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem in using the field?

Comment: Can I confirm: do you **want** the same instance each time? or do you want a **different** instance each time?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the main reason is to have as little as possible double code. There are many `Derived`s from one `Base`, and they all have a class-wide array. To be precise: the array holds a list of supported features which can vary per `Derived`.

Comment: @MarcGravell I want the same instance each time. It is fixed per `Derived` class.

Comment: So... you just don't like having the static field / initializer visible? if so: why? the code you have is direct, working, and obvious: there are good things in code

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree. I am just always trying to code in such a way that it stays maintainable and shorten's programmer time. Also, these kind of things help me learn to get to know C# better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to put the `new int[] { 1,2,3,4 }` part into the getter, that's easy...

```
 private static int[] _someArray = null;
 public override int[] someArray { 
     get {
          return _someArray ?? (_someArray = new int[] { 1,2,3,4 });
     }
 }
```

You'd lose the readonly then, though.

**UPDATE: Generics solution**

Or you could abuse the features of generics for that:

```
// Of course you still want to use the non-generic class Base
abstract class Base {
    public abstract int[] someArray { get; }
}

abstract class Base<T> : Base where T: Base<T> {
     // Will be created once for every T, i.e. every derived class.
     private static int[] _someArray;

     public override int[] someArray {
        get { return _someArray ?? (_someArray = CreateArray()); }
     }

     protected abstract int[] CreateArray();
}

sealed class Derived : Base<Derived> {
     protected sealed override int[] CreateArray() { 
         return new int[] { 1,2,3,4 };
     }
}

sealed class DerivedB : Base<DerivedB> {
    protected sealed override int[] CreateArray() {
        return new int[] { 2,3,4,5 };
    }
}
```

Note that this only works for one inheritance level, so i sealed some stuff :)

Comment: This could work. If I also put the `_someArray` field in the base class, my derived classes all have just one getter.

Comment: He don't want to use a field at all.

Comment: @BartFriederichs You can't put _someArray into the base class, because then you wouldn't have one array per derived class but just one from the base class. If you want something static to each derived class, you won't get around declaring it in the derived class.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, using a field is not the main issue here. The main issue is code re-use.

Comment: @TimSchmelter He didn't explicitly state that.

Comment: The title says: "Returning a static array **without using a class field**" and the question "Is it possible to directly return some kind of object, which stays the same for all objects of class Derived?".

Comment: @Botz3000 you are right. In that case it still introduces double code and the field issue becomes important.

Comment: @Botz3000 beat me by 30 seconds. What's the purpose of Holder class?

Comment: @defaultlocale No idea, confused something. was already removing that :)

Comment: @BartFriederichs I just added a new solution based on the features of generics. I think that avoids duplication good enough.

Comment: @Botz3000 Actually Holder itself had a purpose to make a field in base class readonly  :) One more question: why do we need generics here?

Comment: @defaultlocale readonly doesn't matter that much because Holder.Value was still mutable :) Each closed generic type with a different type parameter has its own set of static members. Base<Derived> and Base<DerivedB> are treated as different classes, so each has its own static int[]. Having a static field in a non-generic class means you only have one static field.

Comment: @Botz3000 I believe `CreateArray` must be `sealed` in derived classes

Comment: @defaultlocale Yes, you're right, it should. Or the derived classes should be sealed, because this only works for one level of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know that will not work in C#. You can either use a field or create a variable in the property/method. In VB.NET you have the `Static` keyword for local variables(see below).

You have commented that you have many derived classes and you don't want to have a static field array for each derived class. I would suggest to use a different approach then. You could f.e. use a static `Dictionary` in your base class and an enum for each derived class:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract DerivedType Type { get; }

    protected static readonly Dictionary<DerivedType, int[]> SomeDict;

    static Base()
    {
        SomeDict = new Dictionary<DerivedType, int[]>();
        SomeDict.Add(DerivedType.Type1, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        SomeDict.Add(DerivedType.Type2, new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 });
        SomeDict.Add(DerivedType.Type3, new int[] { 5, 6, 7 });
        // ...
    }

    public static int[] SomeArray(DerivedType type)
    {
        return SomeDict[type];
    }
}

public enum DerivedType
{
    Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, Type5
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override DerivedType Type
    {
        get { return DerivedType.Type1; }
    }
}
```

---

In VB.NET, however, it is possible using a [static local variable](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/pages/7717.aspx) using the [`Static`-keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
MustInherit Class Base
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property someArray() As Integer()
End Class

Class Derived
    Inherits Base
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property someArray() As Integer()
        Get
            Static _someArray As Int32() = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4}
            Return _someArray
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

`_someArray` will be the same for every instance of `Derived`.

Comment: Yes, that would have been my first solution, but C# doesn't support that.